# Problem with message_filters::cache

Tags: ros-melodic, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "ros/message_traits.h"
#include "message_filters/subscriber.h"
#include "message_filters/cache.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

```
message_filters::Cache<std_msgs::String> cache;

void some_function (const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg)
{
    cache.add(msg);

    std::cout << "Oldest time cached is " << cache.getOldestTime() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Last time received is " << cache.getLatestTime() << std::endl << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "caching_example");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  cache.setCacheSize(100);
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/chatter", 1, some_function);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

---

when building through catkin_make I get errors:

> In file included from /home/great_user/catkin_ws/src/marker/src/newOrganization.cpp:4:0:
> /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/cache.h: In instantiation of ‘ros::Time message_filters::Cache::getOldestTime() const [with M = std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void >]’:
> /home/great_user/catkin_ws/src/marker/src/newOrganization.cpp:13:66:   required from here
> /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/cache.h:321:44: error: ‘value’ is not a member of 
> ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void >, void>’
> oldest_time = mt::TimeStamp::value(*cache_.front().getMessage());
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/cache.h: In instantiation of ‘ros::Time 
> message_filters::Cache::getLatestTime() const [with M = std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void >]’:
> /home/great_user/catkin_ws/src/marker/src/newOrganization.cpp:14:66:   required from here
> /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/cache.h:304:44: error: ‘value’ is not a member of 
> ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void >, void>’
> latest_time = mt::TimeStamp::value(*cache_.back().getMessage());
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/cache.h: In instantiation of ‘void 
> message_filters::Cache::add(const EventType&) [with M = std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void >; 
> message_filters::Cache::EventType = ros::MessageEvent<const std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void > >]’:
> /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/cache.h:121:8:   required from ‘void 
> message_filters::Cache::add(const MConstPtr&) [with M = std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void >; 
> message_filters::Cache::MConstPtr = boost::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void > >]’
> /home/great_user/catkin_ws/src/marker/src/newOrganization.cpp:11:18:   required from here
> /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/cache.h:146:52: error: ‘value’ is not a member of 
> ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void >, void>’
> ros::Time evt_stamp = mt::TimeStamp::value(*evt.getMessage());
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/cache.h:147:63: error: ‘value’ is not a member of 
> ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void >, void>’
>
> while(rev_it != cache_.rend() && mt::TimeStamp::value(*(*rev_it).getMessage()) > evt_stamp)
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> marker/CMakeFiles/organize.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'marker/CMakeFiles/organize.dir
> /src/newOrganization.cpp.o' failed
> make[2]: *** [marker/CMakeFiles/organize.dir/src/newOrganization.cpp.o] Error 1
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2222: recipe for target 'marker/CMakeFiles/organize.dir/all' failed
> make[1]: *** [marker/CMakeFiles/organize.dir/all] Error 2
> Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

---

I tried so

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
ros::init(argc, argv, "caching_example");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

cache.setCacheSize(100);
message_filters::Subscriber<marker::mkzBlaFeedbackBla> subs (nh,"/test",10);
message_filters::Cache<marker::mkzBlaFeedbackBla> cache(subs, 100);

std::cout << "Oldest time cached is " << cache.getOldestTime() << std::endl;

ros::spin();
return 0
}
```

the error remains

the text of the message, then compiled into the header

float32 batteryCharge
float32 batteryVoltage
float32 chargeCurrentOfTheBattery
bool routingTaskReady
bool routingTaskDownload
bool readiness
uint8 errorCode

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307914/problem-with-message_filters::cache/) by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`message_filters` classes can only be used with messages that have `Header`s (in principle). `std_msgs/String` doesn't have a header.

See #q60568 and #q197811 for two previous questions about this.

---

Edit: to work-around this, `Cache` supports `Header`less messages: see the last section of the documentation of [message_filters/Cache](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Cache). Unfortunately:

> This is currently only available in Python.

---

Edit:

> the error remains

> the text of the message, then compiled into the header

> ```
> float32 batteryCharge
> ```

```
float32 batteryVoltage
float32 chargeCurrentOfTheBattery
bool routingTaskReady
bool routingTaskDownload
bool readiness
uint8 errorCode
```

I don't know what you mean by "compiled into the header", but the issue would appear to be that your message doesn't contain a field called `header` of type [std_msgs/Header](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html).

The `header` field would contain the `stamp`, which is the timestamp that `message_filters` needs.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on 2018-11-08**:
thanks I understand

**Comment by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on 2018-11-08**:
I have a message that has its header file, I added it and still the error persists

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-08**:
If you've changed your code/setup/build then I would suggest to update your question text to show exactly what you're doing now. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Do *not* overwrite your current question. Just edit it and append the new information.

**Comment by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on 2018-11-12**:
@gvdhoorn, added a new version of the code

**Comment by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on 2018-11-12**:
@gvdhoorn, I created my custom message (msg).it's called mkzBlaFeedbackBla and he msg file contains the packet marker. Then I added my Cmake name to my message and got a header. and then I use it in my code to receive and receive messages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-12**:
That sounds all fine, but the problem is with the `.msg` file. It does not contain a field with the name `header` and with the type `std_msgs/Header`. The problem is not with a C++ header file.